# How do reflection tokens distribute transactions fee to everyone wallets without doing an insane amount of transactions and running up alot of gas fee

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

How do reflection tokens distribute transactions fees to everyone's wallets without doing an insane amount of transactions and running up alot of gas fees while at the same time giving them more tokens according to how large their position is

Answer (score 0):

For reflection tokens everyones balance is a formula, not a fixed integer value.

```
Simplified example: 

User A buys 10 tokens. 

Current Reflection multiplier = 1.0

getBalance(user A) equals 10 * 1.0 = 10

Something happens which increases the reflection multiplier to 1.1

getBalance(user A) equals 10 * 1.1 = 11
```

The users balance changes without any transfer transactions having to be done.

Comment: How would this formula work when they want to send out those tokens.

Comment: @devontaylor You can look at some reflection token code and see how it works. https://github.com/reflectfinance/reflect-contracts/blob/main/contracts/REFLECT.sol